# Convert certificate in BIN format to X509 format

Tags: ssl, https, openssl

I have read this good article on running tomcat in https and implemented it.

http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps/

It is working fine and my tomcat is running in https mode.

But the problem is i got the certificate in **BIN format**. I need it in **X509 format** so that i can use it as an raw resource for my Android project

I have used java keytool to create it.Can i use OpenSSL to convert it into X509 Format or java keytool is sufficient?

I am new to this securities stuff.

Please point me in the right direction and clear my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think keytool already handles certificates in X509 format only. You should have generated .keystore file. You can export certificate from it using command:

> keytool -export -alias mycert -keystore mykeystore.bin -file certificatefile.cer

Comment: Thanks for the response Nilesh.In the url above it was mentioned that .BIN file is actually keystore file.what should i do now?

Comment: use above command with additional parameter -keystore <your bin file name>

Comment: do you need to use private key as well? or you just want to add server certificate on android phone in trusted store to avoid browser warning? [Edit]: See if this helps you: http://conshell.net/wiki/index.php/Keytool_to_OpenSSL_Conversion_tips

Comment: I just want to add server certificate on android phone in truested store so that it accepts connections to this server only without any warning.I am looking to do as told in below URL  [link]http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

Comment: ok. In that case extracting certificate and installing it on phone should be sufficient. You can use above command.

Comment: @Nilesh-In the blog post i mentioned above,they are creating a BKS keystore with the server certificate.Is it enough if i convert my JKS keystore to BKS keystore?it is possible using portecle

Comment: If you just want to extract certificate from keystore to install it on phone, then converting entire keystore to other formats does not matter. Just export the certificate and install it on phone.

Comment: @Nilesh-I was able to extract the certificate in PEM encoded format and i created a new BKS keystore with that certificate as told in above blog.I will give a try with that keystore in android.Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can use OpenSSL to convert the certificate and keys to and from the following formats

- Standard PEM
- DER / Binary
- PKCS#7 (aka P7B)
- PKCS#12 (aka PFX)

In your case, given a private key file and digital certificate in standard PEM,
convert them both to pkcs12 format using the following steps:

**Step 1: Convert the PEMs to a single PKCS12 file**

```
    OpenSSL> pkcs12 -export -in CE_cert.cer -inkey CE_prv_key_PEM.key -out
pkcs12_KeyStore.p12 -name ce_cert_prv_key
```

Heres the doc for [OpenSSL PKCS12](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html#) command.

**Step 2: Import the PKCS12 file created in step 1 into the new JKS**

```
C:\>keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore pkcs12_KeyStore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass somepass -srcalias ce_cert_prv_key -destk
eystore path/to/JavaKeyStore_KS.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass somepass -destkeypass somepass
```

Now after having the certificate and private key in the JKS format, you can use this JSK key store in Tomcat.

Comment: PEM is not and never was a standard for certificates. Binary DER is a standard form for X.509 certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the Response Zaki.After some googling i found that i have a JKS keystore.Are you asking me to create a new keystore?

Comment: @Sreeram, Yes, create a new jks keystore with your cert & priv key files  to be used in your android project.

Comment: @Zaki-Nilesh has given a way to convert the already JKS keystore into PKCS12 format.Refer to the site he has given in the comment.

Comment: @Sreeram, the Step 2 in my answer does exactly that, ie, importing the certificate and keys from a pkcs12 keystore into an existing or new JKS keystore.