# Get certificate information from .bin file on linux?

Tags: linux, openssl, certificate, client-certificates, bin

Can ".bin" files contain certificate information? If so how might I get that information from the file? Basically I am just trying to verify the signed certificate expiration date. Thanks.

Comment: What does `file myfile.bin` say? If it just says "data", how about `openssl x509 -text -inform der -in myfile.bin`?

Comment: Try  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595692/convert-certificate-in-bin-format-to-x509-format

Comment: This might get more and better attention in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), as it has really nothing to do with programming which is the [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.